# Filebeat collects logs and pushes them to Kafka error

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

**1.My version information**

```
jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
kibana-6.5.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
elasticsearch-6.5.0.tar.gz
logstash-6.5.0.tar.gz
filebeat-6.5.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz
zookeeper-3.4.12.tar.gz
```

**2.Problem description**

I have a log file in XML format. I use filebeat to collect this file and push it to Kafka Content garbled.

Here's my filebeat configuration

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log

  enabled: true

  paths:
    - /data/reporttg/ChannelServer.log

  include_lines: ['\<\bProcID.*\<\/ProcID\b\>']


### Filebeat modules

filebeat.config.modules:

  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  reload.enabled: false

### Elasticsearch template setting

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3


### Kibana

setup.kibana:

### Kafka

output.kafka:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["IP:9092", "IP:9092", "IP:9092"]
  topic: houry

### Procesors 
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

My log content

```
<OrigDomain>ECIP</OrigDomain>
<HomeDomain>UCRM</HomeDomain>
<BIPCode>BIP2A011</BIPCode>
<BIPVer>0100</BIPVer>
<ActivityCode>T2000111</ActivityCode>
<ActionCode>1</ActionCode>
<ActionRelation>0</ActionRelation>
<Routing>
    <RouteType>01</RouteType>
    <RouteValue>13033935743</RouteValue>
</Routing>
<ProcID>PROC201901231142020023206514</ProcID>
<TransIDO>SSP201901231142020023206513</TransIDO>
<TransIDH>2019012311420257864666</TransIDH>
<ProcessTime>20190123114202</ProcessTime>
<Response>
    <RspType>0</RspType>
    <RspCode>0000</RspCode>
    <RspDesc>success</RspDesc>
</Response>
```

Test regular expressions

[image: Correct expression]

**3.Start filebeat and view Kafka content**

[image: Wrong content]

4.I tested that it was normal for filebeat to collect content and push it to logstash.

How should this problem be solved?

Comment: Your data is "correct". You're just seeing the `<>` characters as their encoded values

Comment: But I need to use logstash to extract the information from it as log parsing.Too much is coded.It's very difficult for me to filter the encoded logs with the filter of logstash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to include the XML tags, I would recommend you use a [regex grouping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/regexp-support.html#grouping)

Something like so

```
'<ProcID>(PROC[0-9]+)<\/ProcID>'
```

Comment: I need the XML tag to collect the content as it is, and then use logstash to filter the log content.

Comment: Okay, then I'm not sure if there is a setting to not have unicode encoded characters come back in the parsed response. Plus, I can't tell how you are viewing the kafka content. Doesn't look like a kafka-console-consumer tool

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have found a way to solve the problem.I use tools to view content by kafkatool